# How to fix the systemd file permissions?

Tags: boot, permissions, systemd

I have a raspberry pi python3 program "monitor.py" that works from the terminal
But it fails to run when I start it from boot.

**Check status:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status monitor.service

● monitor.service - Service to start monitor in terminal on desktop  
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/monitor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-01 14:56:31 MST; 55s ago
  Process: 624 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/monitor.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/monitor.log (code=exited, status=1/  
 Main PID: 624 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  

Jan 01 14:56:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Service to start monitor in terminal on desktop.  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi python3[624]: Traceback (most recent call last):  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi python3[624]:   File "/home/pi/monitor.py", line 6, in <module>  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi python3[624]:     **cf = open (cmdfile,"w")**  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi python3[624]: PermissionError: [Errno 13]   **Permission denied: 'cmdfile.txt'**  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monitor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monitor.service: Unit entered failed state.  
Jan 01 14:56:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Check for permissions:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l cmdfile.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pi pi 1 Dec 31 21:09 cmdfile.txt
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l monitor.py
-rwxrw-rw- 1 pi pi 506 Jan  1 09:50 monitor.py
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/monitor.service
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 224 Dec 30 13:09 /lib/systemd/system/monitor.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /home/pi/Desktop/monitor.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 0 Jan  1 10:29 /home/pi/Desktop/monitor.log
```

**The program monitor.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

cmdfile = "cmdfile.txt"
cf = open(cmdfile,"w")
cmd = 1
cf.write(str(cmd))
cf.close
isRunning = cmd
cntr = 0
wait = 10

while isRunning == cmd:
    cntr += 1
    print("Hello World:", cntr)
    cf = open(cmdfile,"r")
    cmd = int(cf.read())
    cf.close
    if isRunning != cmd:
        print("check interrupt")
        if cmd == 0:
            import os
            os.system("sudo reboot -h now")
        else: # incremented
            exit()

    time.sleep(wait)
```

**The systemctl monitor.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to start monitor in terminal on desktop
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/monitor.py &  

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Enable the new service:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo chmod 744 /lib/systemd/system/monitor.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl enable monitor.service
```

**Test the program:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./monitor.py  #note dot at start of the line
Hello World: 1
Hello World: 2
Hello World: 3
```

**Restart:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo reboot
```

**Check Status:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status monitor.service
```

**Stop:**  (requires password)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl stop monitor.service
```

**Edit again with:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl --full edit monitor.service
```

**Edit Note -- modified the above:** 
in monitor.service I changed the following.
Was:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/monitor.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/monitor.log
```

Now:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/monitor.py &
```

To remove the log (simplify) and add the & (to exit)
It still fails but there is one less thing to question.

Comment: This is NOT a Pi question, and has nothing to do with file permissions. I do not know what the program is supposed to do or whether it will work BUT **every single file needs to have a FULL path**. Startup programs which create files or attempt to output text are generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Milliways Why are services that create output files a bad idea? Logs seems a very acceptable and very common output file. Outputting text likewise provides logging capability to systemd which will return you the output on request.

Comment: A unit is working as a service in the background. So sending a program already running in the background to the background again with prefix `&` is a very bad idea. Don't do that. The program is then completely out of control from systemd. If you want the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons then you must use `Type=forking` in Section [Service]. See `man systemd.service`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add a [working directory](http://%60https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=%60) to your unit file as the Pi user won't have write access to put cmdfile.txt into the root of the volume (or whereever systemd roots itself).

in your Unit file add...

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
```

...and reload the daemon. You can change this to where you want but it must be somewhere `pi` can write to.

Comment: per @tobyd added under [Service] `WorkingDirectory=/home/pi`  per @Ingo restored `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/monitor.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/monitor.log`  Success!! Thank you. On testing reboot I set cmdfile.txt to 0 externally. The app read the file and Reboot worked. Now I am in an infinite reboot loop. I suspect the system postpones a write to the file. I need to force a write before continuing. Now I am researching `systemctl disable monitor.service` It looks like the Shift key will allow me to reload the operating system. Sometimes it is hard to recognize progress.